# The menu template is incorrectly displayed in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, menu, drawer

I write a program and faced a problem when creating a menu. I even took the menu template, but the meaning remained the same. Below is an example of a template that does not work for me from Android Studio! Well, my code is that way.

[As should be the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6odfE.png).

[In my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFiM6.png).

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view"
```

Due to such lines we get the previous result.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/menu_tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/menu_share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="@string/menu_send" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

If we remove those two lines of code, then we will [not see the normal display of icons and some text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4NyC.png).

Just in case, add the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "file.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

How can this be fixed at all? Many thanks.

Comment: Please check logcat if there any error & share image for it if there is any error

Comment: As per my understanding, you are talking about the navigation drawer. You need to check your layouts and the activity code regarding how you are presenting the drawer. You must read about designing the navigation drawer here https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui

Comment: Thanks, I looked at logcat. There are a lot of mistakes. But the most interesting thing is that I launched the emulator, everything works fine on it and is displayed too, but at the time of development / editing you saw problems